# Transferring Development Wordpress To Live Wordpress Without Issues

Tags: wordpress, plugins, transfer

I am looking for a way to port one wordpress install across to another site.

For example, say I have:

```
development.example.com 
example.com
```

I want to transfer everything from development.example.com to example.com

Transferring the domain name is always a pain for me and I am hoping someone can help me.

After transferring to a new domain and hosting, I normally have to go into the wordpress database into the options table and change two fields.

siteurl and home (I change these to my new domain name)

I can then run example.com/wp-admin and I will be able to login.

The above works fine on the basic setup, but the issue I am having is that when you have lots of different plugins all adding options and other fields to the database it turns into a bit of a nightmare.

I normally have to remove the plugin folder and reinstall them one by one, and then use a search and replace plugin to change all the options from.

```
search: development.example.com 
replace: example.com
```

This all seems like a very long winded process considering when I build with codeigniter you only have to change the url in one place config.php and then just run a

```
cp -rf development.example.com/* example.com
```

Could someone advise me on how they normally run a transfer with wordpress where all this search replace and login issues aren’t needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all the details on the [When Your Domain Name or URLs Change](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#When_Your_Domain_Name_or_URLs_Change) section in the Codex.

For replacing links, the [Velvet Blues Update URLs](http://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) plugin works well for me.

Comment: Hi RRikesh great thanks for the info the update_option('siteurl', 'http://your.domain.name/the/path' ); great to know.